# Susy Rem and pixel fallbacks

Tags: pixel, compass-sass, susy-compass

I have specified my grid with rems in Susy and I'm not getting a pixel fallback. I am using Susy 1.0.9 and Compass 0.12.2. The `$rem-with-px-fallback` var is set to true but I don;t get pixel fallbacks for the `span-columns` mixin. Any ideas? It's causing issues in IE8 where my column elements are not displaying correctly due to only having rem widths, not even a percentage width is set.

Answer (score 0):

You're right. Susy was designed originally for fluid/magic grids, and it looks like the static option was missed when rem support was added. Feel free to file a bug.

Comment: Thanks. added a Github issue for this. Any idea on when a fix will be available and is there an ETA for Susy Next? Much appreciate all the help you've provided on Susy over the replies you've posted. Highly appreciated!

Comment: Public ETA's are difficult on open source projects, but I have a personal deadline for Susy Next. :)

Comment: Fair Enough, makes sense. Looking forward to it and I hope all the rem with pixel fallback stuff will make an appearance in it too.